# Dimension of intersection of two manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

For any $f\in C^\infty(X)$, $X$ smooth manifold.  Define
$$X_{df}:=\{(x,df_x): x\in X, df_x= T^*_x X\}$$
$$X_0:=\{(x,\zeta): \zeta=0 \text{ in } T_x^*X\}$$

In the exercise we are asked for proof: If $X$ is compact, $$\#\{X_{df}\cap X_0\}\geq 2$$

Comment: This seems to be an absurdly convoluted way to state that $df$ has two zeros!

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that, when $X$ is compact, we can find an $f$ where equality is obtained iff $X$ is homeomorphic to a sphere.  This result is due to Reeb, I believe.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Absolutely. Anyone interested can find this in Morse Theory by Milnor.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Global max and global min.